# Regex to replace He or She with He/She

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex to replace `He` or `She` with `He/She`

I have the following scenarios:

1. Start of line
2. end of line
3. before or after a punctuation mark

I tried this

```
str.replace(/((\s|^|/[^!-~]/)He($|\s|/[^!-~]/)|(\s|^|/[^!-~]/)She($|\s|/[^!-~]/))/g, "He/She")
```

It is throwing an Exception... I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: Can you add the exception that is being thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your regex: You have multiple unescaped slashes (`/`) in it, which are in fact not necessary. I simplified and improved your regex a bit and you can directly use it like this:

```
(\s|^|[^!\-~])(He|She)($|\s|[^!\-~])
```

And replace it with:

```
$1He/She$3
```

In JavaScript, it would be like this:

```js
var text = "He went to school";
var result = text.replace(/(\s|^|[^!\-~])(He|She)($|\s|[^!\-~])/g, '$1He/She$3');
console.log(result);
```

This will match any of your characters (white space, `!`, etc.) before and after and you won't lose it, because it is added to the result again. Otherwise, you would need positive lookaheads/lookbehinds, which are not supported in JavaScript (lookbehinds).

I would probably add a few more of those characters (e.g. `?`, `.`, which both need to be escaped). If you want to match also `he` and `she`, you have to use the case insensitive flag `i`. Be aware, that the replacement of `he` would then be `He/She` with upper cases.

*Edit* There was a bug in the regex: `[^!-~]` matches everything except characters from `!` until `~` (because of the dash in between). You need to escape it to `[^!\-~]`.

---

You can also just use word boundaries, like this:

```js
var text = "Sheldon went to school with her, but he did not like it.";
var result = text.replace(/\b(He|She)\b/g, 'He/She').replace(/\b(he|she)\b/g, 'he/she');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Javascript compiler exception: illegal character (null.null.script; line 2) in:
var str = "He is good person.She the is a good she person";
var ans = str.replace((\s|^|[^!-~])(He|She)($|\s|[^!-~]), "$1He/She$2");

Comment: @T.Bedia You cannot just write a regex expression without quotes or slashes.. I've added an example...

Comment: how about the ".She"

Comment: @T.Bedia There was a bug in the regex. Check the corrected answer above.

Comment: This would also replace words starting with He/She, example

Sheldon. this should not happen, how can we avoid that?

When He/She is placed before or after a punctuation mark, only then it would be replaced

Comment: You can just use word boundaries instead: `"Sheldon went to school with her, but he did not like it.".replace(/\b(He|She)\b/g, 'He/She').replace(/\b(he|she)\b/g, 'he/she');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've made it so complicated. It seems like you don't care about correct capitalization, so:

```js
var str = "He likes to play baseball while she likes riding horses. She thinks baseball is dumb. She doesn't know if he would like to ride horses also... would he?";

console.log(str.replace(/\bs?he\b/ig, 'He/She'));
```

(I apologize for the moronic sentence.)

`\b` is used as a word delimiter.

`s?he` matches "she" or "he".

`ig` is used to ignore case and search globally.